# Select without prepared statements in perl

Tags: database, perl, prepared-statement, dbi

My database does not support prepared statements, is there any way to run select query on this database without prepare statements in perl?

Code Snippet:

```
my $query = $conn->prepare("select a, b from my_table");
$query->execute();
```

Error:

```
DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  cannot execute PREPARE
```

Comment: just use `prepare` and db driver will take care of the rest

Comment: Which database? Is it DBD::Something, or what?

Comment: @TLP I want to harvest result of select, do does not allow that. http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#do

Comment: @mpapec nope, I get an error, because currently db does not support it (a modified version of postgresql).

Comment: @Dallaylaen it is DBD-Pg

Comment: Show the code you are using, and the errors you are getting.

Comment: What good is that code? We already know that you used a prepare method from somewhere. Show which modules you are using, and how you create the database object. And you should probably use the errstr function to get the error. And probably report the version of the module and Perl.

Comment: if it is modified version of `postgresql` perhaps it needs its own driver. btw, enterprisedb?

Comment: @TLP and I simple ask that my database doesn't support prepared statements, and I want to learn that is there any way to use select without prepared statements.

Comment: @metdos Well, its been 2 hours and you have no answer. That should tell you that your question cannot be answered in its current form. In my experience, it is more likely a user error than a software error.

Comment: @TLP Isn't my question clear? I want to just send a query to database and harvest results without using prepared statements.

Comment: Can you identify which version of Perl, DBI, DBD::Pg and PostgreSQL you are using.  The DBI specification requires `$sth = $dbh->prepare(...);` followed by `$sth->execute()` to work, so the driver would be (is?) unusable if it doesn't.  About the only thing I can see that could go wrong is if the `prepare` fails, you (should) get an invalid statement handle, but it isn't obvious that that's the problem.  Did you connect with `{RaiseError=>1}` and/or `{PrintError=>1}` in the connection attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `$conn->{'pg_server_prepare'} = 0` to disable server-side prepared statements.

Comment: Yeap, that simple. Thanks.